# How to continuously import data from external service into SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, concurrency, bulkinsert, isolation-level

I have nearly a hundred services sending data to our message queue. This data is processed by Java service and loaded into import tables in our SQL Server. After data is loaded, a few procedures are executed that load this data into proper tables. Recently we had to add new instances of service reading and loading messages. It was suggested that we should change database isolation model to snapshot (I'm not very accustomed with databases so I simply did what was proposed). Unfortunately we had a lot of problems with it, so we had to duplicate import tables and aforementioned procedures - this of course resulted in a huge mess that I'm currently trying to clean up.

My current understanding is such that snapshot isolation was suggested so that services could work using the same table without problems and errors that we encountered stem from some misunderstanding or improper implementation on our (developers) side.

My question is: is it possible, and if yes then how, to bulk load data into single table, transform it and load into target table (everything in parallel, so lets say that there are 3 or 4 services doing it) in a way that causes no deadlocks or data loss.

Our SQL Server is: Microsoft SQL Server 2014 (SP2-GDR) (KB4019093) - 12.0.5207.0 (X64)

I don't know much more, but I know that for example we don't have support for partitioning or online index creation - maybe this will help somehow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended modifying services loading data and import tables in such a way that each record loaded has its own identifier. Also services no longer execute import procedures, they are scheduled using SQL Agent and run once per minute. Solution is really simple and while on average data is stored in destination tables 30 seconds after they are received by the services, this is something that we can live with - we can load much, much, MUCH more data that way.